# How to debug register_setting callback function

Tags: plugins, options

I am using the following code:

```
register_setting(
        'myplugin_options', //setting group name
        'myplugin_options', //option name that will be stored in the database
        'myplugin_validate_options'//optional callback function
);

function myplugin_validate_options($input) {
    //how can i print $input to the screen or view the output of this function for debugging purpsoses?

}
```

I just need to know how we can debug our validation callback functions. From what I see they can not be output to the screen so it makes writing correct code inside of them difficult.

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried var_dump?

Comment: I do love me some var_dump. 90%  of the time, it gives you everything you need, every time.

Comment: Yeah it looks like var_dump does the trick. I also noticed that print_r works too, but just a plain old echo does not output to the screen, strangely enough.

Comment: That's probably because `$input` contains an array of data, you can't echo arrays.

Comment: You can echo arrays, it will just print Array... Even if you do echo 'hi'; it will not output. Give it a try. Debugging this function is a PIA.

Answer (score 7):

The dirty and only way I've founded:

```
function myplugin_validate_options($input) {
    var_dump($input);
    exit;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

When echoing ( echo($var) ) within 'library' code (ie. before the page is being built, as in the case here of register_setting) these statements will typically print just after the opening  tag in the HTML but will often not show up there.  I use PHP's built-in function error_log() to print whatever I want directly to PHP's error log.  Then I can just open that file (usually php_error.log somewhere) and see the output.  Work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Set up xdebug, the only way to do any real debugging! What is your development set-up? Are you running your code from localhost or using vagrant?

Answer (score 0):

none of the above solutions worked for me,
I even tried the debug statements to a file.

A work around which does the job is

add a call to undefined function after all your debug statements, then the out put is printed to the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `add_settings_error` function like this:

```
    add_settings_error(
        'plugin_settings', // Slug title of setting
        'wporg_message', // Slug-name , Used as part of 'id' attribute in HTML output.
        __( $input ), // HERE YOU CAN DEBUG YOUR CODE
        'updated' // Message type, controls HTML class. Accepts 'error' or 'updated'.
    );
```